# Webclient with Spring Boot 3.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

Has anyone tried using WebClient with Spring Boot 3.x?
If so, is there a way to instrument or intercept any http client calls made by the client application, that go uncaptured in Spring Boot 3.x?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?